# 'iexplore.exe' processes number doesn't match number of IE opened tabs

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, windows-7, process

In Windows 7 i open 10 tabs in IE 9 (didn't check it in other versions of Windows or IE) and then open tasks manager. Count number of "iexplore.exe" processes and it's 6. Open 5 more tabs and now it's 7. Can someone please explain me why number of tabs doesn't match number of processes in this case?

Comment: Is your question somehow related to programming which is what this site is about?

Comment: Tab isolation can be done at the thread level, not necessarily at the process level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple tabs are hosted by a single process. There's nothing stating that tabs have to be 1 to 1 with processes.